# Stuck with Codecademy JS course ('The Story So Far: If, Else, and Loops' 2/14)

Tags: javascript

**Try this code**

```
var isEven = function(number) {


    if (number % 2 === 0) {
        return true;
    } else if (isNaN(number)) {
        return "Not a number";
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}


isEven();
```

This must work for you. I got this one as correct !!!!

Answer (score 2):

You get a `ReferenceError` because there is no `isNan` function. Its called [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN).

Answer (score 0):

```
var isEven = function(number) {

  if (number % 2 === 0) {
      return true;

    } else if (NaN(number)) {
        return "Your input is not a number!";

    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var isEven = function(number) {
  // Your code goes here!
  if(number%2){
      return true;
  }
  else if(isNan (number)){
      return "Your input is not a number.";
  }
  else{
      return false;
  }
};`enter code here`
```

Comment: Please explain how your code provides a solution to the question. This will help the OP understand and also future searchers.

Answer (score 0):

Check it out:

```
var isEven = function(number) {
   if (isNaN (number)) {
      return "The input was not a number!";
   }  
   else if (number % 2 === 0) {
      return true;
   } 
   else if (isNaN (number) === true) {
      return "Your input isn't a number!";
     }
   else {
      return false;
      }
   };
```

Comment: The second check for `isNaN(number)` is dead code. If it is true, the first body will be executed, otherwise, the second one won't be executed as well as the first, falling down to the last `else` clause.